# Purpose of adding unnecessary parentheses in a logical expression with && and ||

Tags: c#

In the following C# example,

```
bool isTrue = (isP1 && isQ1) ||
    (isP2 && isQ2) ||
    (isP3 && isQ3);
```

the parentheses are not necessary, since `&&` has a higher priority than `||`.

But I heard that

> the parentheses are added for clarity and **because the logic may fail
>   otherwise doing left-to-right PEMDAS handling**

What does "because the logic may fail otherwise doing left-to-right PEMDAS handling" mean here?

When doing left-to-right PEMDAS handling, does `&&` not have a higher priority than `||`?

Thanks.

Comment: It means somebody didn’t internalise the operator precedence rules (beyond PEMDAS) — or thinks other readers of the code maybe don’t. Fair enough (especially since they differ between programming languages).

Comment: If you need to think about whether you need the parentheses or not, then it might be better to use them.

Comment: Sometimes it's not only useful to use parentheses, but introducing explanatory variables which give readable names for conditions. E.g. instead of `isP2 && isQ2` you can use `isRentExpired`

Comment: If you want to know if the code is equivalent with and without the parenthesis, then run it, remove them, run it again, and see if the results are the same.  Or you could just look up the operator precedence if you want to know; it's readily available.

Comment: Using parentheses not only ensures that the reader will know what the code means, but also ensures that the reader will know *that the programmer knew* what the code means.  Without the parentheses, a reader might have no problem knowing how the compiler would see the code, but might have a harder time knowing whether the code correctly prescribed the behavior intended by the programmer's intended.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the `&&` operator has a higher priority than `||`, but if parentheses are used it helps third persons to identify the purpose intended by the programmer and also it clearly explains the way of the evaluation that is done. To conclude it is used to allow for a better understanding of the program written.